# how to get rule for every predicted row in C5.0 algorithm in R

Tags: r

I am fitting the model wth C5.0 in following way

```
model <- c5.0(Target ~.,data=df,rules=TRUE,trials=10)
```

After fitting this model on data,I want to have the rule for every predicted row.

I am using following function

```
pathpred <- function(object, ...) {
   ## coerce to "party" object if necessary
   if(!inherits(object, "party")) object <- as.party(object)

   ## get standard predictions (response/prob) and collect in data frame
   rval <- data.frame(response = predict(object, type = "response", ...))
   rval$prob <- predict(object, type = "prob", ...)

   ## get rules for each node
   rls <- partykit:::.list.rules.party(object)

   ## get predicted node and select corresponding rule
   rval$rule <- rls[as.character(predict(object, type = "node", ...))]

   return(rval)
 }

 pred <- pathpred(model)
 pred[c(1, 51, 101), ]
```

But it gives me an error `Error in if (!n.cat[i]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Above code works perfect if I fit the algorithm using `rpart`